# p5 mouse follow

Tags: javascript, canvas, processing

I'm trying to achieve a certain mouse follow effect in p5.js (canvas) where I want the object to follow the mouse in the manner it does here: https://alpha.editor.p5js.org/momentiris/sketches/BkhShLPpM, but with a "in-back" style easing applied to it. In other words, I want the object to attract to the mouse, but pass the coordinate it's attracting to by, lets say 10%, and then go back to the coordinate it's actually seeking.

If you look at the example sketch I added, this should be applied to all mouse follow inside the triggering rectangle, and not just on the initial triggering move.

Its made in p5.js but I'm certain the maths are applicable everywhere, so requested help is not necessarily limited to p5/canvas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to use the math from Penner's [Elastic EaseOut](https://github.com/jesusgollonet/processing-penner-easing/blob/master/src/Elastic.java)

```
float easeOut(float t, float b, float c, float d) {
  if (t==0) return b;  
  if ((t/=d)==1) return b+c;  
  float p=d*.3f;
  float a=c; 
  float s=p/4;
  return (a*(float)Math.pow(2, -10*t) * (float)Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*(float)Math.PI)/p ) + c + b);
}
```